# Django how to connect user profile model with comment model for showing data from user profile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I want to show user profile picture publicly in my blog comment section. I tried to use foreignkey in my comment model for connect user profile model then use this in my html for showing profile picture but didn't work.

```
 <img src="{{blogcomment.userprofile.profile_pic.url}}"> #didn't show any profile picture until I manually go to admin panel and set foreignkey of userprofile in my blogcomment model.
```

here is my full code:

**userprofile model**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="userprofile")
      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=2000,unique=True,blank=True,null=True)
     
      profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/images/',validators=[validate_file_size,FileExtensionValidator( ['png','jpg'] )],blank=True,null=True)
```

**blogcomment model:**

```
class BlogComment(models.Model):
       blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True,related_name="blogcomment_blog")
       comment = models.TextField(max_length=50000)
       name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     
       userprofile= models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
       user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_comment',blank=True,null=True)
```

**views.py:**

```
   if comment_form.is_valid():
                isinstance = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                isinstance.user = request.user
                isinstance.blog = blog
                isinstance.save()
```

my html template:

```
 {% for q in queryset %}
         {{q.user.first_name}}
         {{q.comment}}
        <img src="{{q.userprofile.profile_pic.url}}">
 {%endfor%}
```

my **froms.py**

```
class CommentFrom(forms.ModelForm):
      captcha = CaptchaField()
      
      class Meta:
          model = BlogComment
          fields = ['name','email','comment','parent','sno','blog','user']
```

my userprofile **forms.py**

```
   class ProfileFroms(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
          model = UserProfile
          fields = ["profile_pic","mobile","country","website_link","skype","twitter"]
```

userprofile views.py

```
class UserProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
      model = UserProfile
      form_class = ProfileFroms
      template_name = 'members/profileupdate.html'
      success_url = reverse_lazy('members:user-profile-private')
```

html template for saving userprofile forms

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{form}}
</form>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML template of thye form, and the (full) view?

Comment: Willem Van Onsem I added html template code and my views.py is very long so here is google drive link of text file where I put my views.py code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wk7mJcGFM-KdsJW24-QtqZS_Vfjmyp1h/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  when I manually go to admin panel and set foreignkey of userprofile in my blogcomment model then it's showing the user profile picture. I think I need to be save userprofile moldel foreignkey in my blogcommnet model when the comment will be created but don't understand how to save it.

Comment: Yes, can you show the `<form>`. Uploading images require some extra logic in the `<form>` template.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I updated my question

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I have not problems in  userprofile forms. pic uploaded in userprofile model via  userprofile forms. Just need to save the foreignkey of  userprofile in my blogcommnet model when the commnet will be created.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem any suggestion ?????

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problems. As Willem Van Onsem said I am missing somethings in my froms. I need to be save userprofile forignkey with my comment model when any new comment posted. I am using this queryset  `UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)`  for  find current id  then pass this id in forms.

```
{%for i in user_profile%}
<input type="hidden" name='userprofile' value="{{i.id}}">
{%endfor%}
```